# How can I force an image to have same height as input field in Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to have an image in my "inline button" that's attached to an input field. However, the image is not scaled to fit the same height as the input field. Here's my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input id="myinput" type="text" class="form-control" name="myinput">
    <div class="input-group-append" id="mySearchButton" >
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" >
         <img style="" src="https://www.google.se/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
      </button>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code will result in a very large button, but I want to resize it to fit the input field better... How?

Comment: Use the `maxHeight` property of css

Comment: @DebarghaRoy: But how can I set it to the same height as the input field... and how do I keep the aspect ratio of the image when changing the height?